# Adding onload to body

Tags: hooks, javascript, plugins

I'm currently trying to develop a plugin that will embed a Google Earth Tour into a WP post / page via a shortcode.

The issue I am running into is that for the tour to load, I have to add an `onload="init()"` into the `<body>` tag.

I can modify a specific template file, but since this is for release, I need to add it dynamically via a hook. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it not possible to use unintrusive Javascript via jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more digging and found a 'better' way to get it working (Google makes it hard to get their damn Earth Tours embedded, and their gadget doesn't work).

I ended up making a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-earth-tours/) that uses a combination of a shortcode and a custom field.

Comment: If you're able, I'd recommend posting the code for the benefit of others who find this post.

Comment: Yeah would be even helpful to better understand for what you have asked for in the first place. Question and Answer should go together.

Comment: For anyone that might want it, here's the plugin. It's hosted on the WP repository http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-earth-tours/

Comment: You can accept your own answer, to indicate that the problem is solved for you.

Answer (score 9):

And here's a jQuery solution (as Mike suggested in his first comment).

```
function add_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_init_script', SCRIPTSRC, 'jquery', '1.0' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_my_scripts' );
```

Then add a script to your plug-in that does this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    init();
});
```

This will start jQuery in no conflict mode (if it isn't already) and add a call to the `init()` method when the document is ready.  It's a safer method to use than `body onready()` because the `onready()` function can only call one thing ... so no one else can hook anything to that or add custom script.  It's better to make your plug-in as unobtrusive as possible so other plug-ins don't interfere or vice-versa.

Comment: I think that yours is on of the preferred methods. I think the jQuery code can even be reduced, because jQuery offers a shortcut to the ready function.

Comment: @EAMann - Can you better explain the jQuery.noConflict()? I've never used and the docs were not clear to me.

Comment: By default, jQuery sets the `$` symbol as a synonym for `jQuery` ... this will break other libraries (Prototype, Scriptaculous, etc) and can break user-defined `$` functions as well.  Using `jQuery.noConflict()` disable this default, but you can still use the `$` function in your code if you pass it in ... so the function I defined above could use `$.ajax` and other native calls *inside* the defined function.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/selekturz-they-iz-serius-bizniss/

Comment: @EAMann - Thanks. I knew about using inside the ready() function but I didn't realize that there would be a conflict if you simply never use the $ outside of a closure. I still don't see what it does. Maybe I should just go research a bit more...

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - By default, jQuery sets the global `$` as an alias for the jQuery object.  Invoking jQuery in `noConflict()` mode [overrides that default](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach. You would add the the `add_action()` call inside your hook, I believe. The JavaScript I include presumes that the init function has already been defined. If it has not, then this will fail, but including the script seems like a problem you've already solved if I'm understanding you right. Note that you don't necessarily need to add it to `wp_foot`, you could just as easily add it to `wp_head`:

```
<?php

function mypluginprefix_onload_init() { ?>
<script language="text/javascript">
// check for the standards-compliant way to add onload events
if ( typeof(window.addEventListener) !== 'undefined' )
    window.addEventListener( "load", init, false );
// or the older msie nonstandard way
else if ( typeof(window.attachEvent) !== 'undefined' ) {
    window.attachEvent( "onload", init );
}
</script>
<?php }

// this goes in your hook
add_action('wp_foot', 'mypluginprefix_onload_event');
?>
```

Comment: Why direct Javascript and not jQuery? jQuery handles all the edge cases where code can run before the page is fully loaded.

Comment: For a simple onload, I think jQuery is overkill. Just attach the handler and be done. jQuery comes with a cost in overhead in terms of download. I love jQuery, but it's not the answer to everything. Now, if jQuery were already queued, then I'd say use it, but my answer does without it.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the potential to do this with jQuery one thing you could do is **hook the `template_include` filter and use `ob_start()`** with a callback. Your callback can then do a string search on `'<body'` and replace it with `'<body onload="init()"'` like the following code does. You should be able to drop it directly in your plugin, just be sure to change the names to follow your plugin's own naming convention:

```
<?php
add_filter('template_include','start_buffer_capture',1);
function start_buffer_capture($template) {
  ob_start('end_buffer_capture');  // Start Page Buffer
  return $template;
}
function end_buffer_capture($buffer) {
  return str_replace('<body','<body onload="init()"',$buffer);
}
```

Note that I would not assume the above code to be fully robust yet if I were you. I doubt it will handle all edge cases since I just threw it together to answer your question but minimally it shows you how to accomplish the normal case, and then with some use-case testing I'm sure you'' get it to handle all the important edge cases (like what if `'<BODY'` is uppercase, etc?)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some JavaScript to dynamically add a callback to the page load, with or without jQuery:

```
function add_onload() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    my_onload_callback = function() { alert('Hello!'); }; // test function

    if( typeof jQuery == "function" ) { 
        jQuery(my_onload_callback); // document.ready
    } else {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onload = my_onload_callback; // body.onload
    }
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_onload' );
```

In your case you would just replace the my_onload_callbacks with your init method.