# Can I change header.php of current theme through a plugin function?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, functions, child-theme

I need to add some html into the header.php but instead of directly changing the header.php of my theme or creating a child theme, how can I do it with just actions and/or hooks?

Comment: Do you want to change the part inside of `<head></head>` or something below?

Comment: @toscho no, the `<header>` inside the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to insert code into the `<head></head>` block, then this hook does it:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_73900_wp_head' );

function wpse_73900_wp_head()
{
    ?>
    <!-- Custom Html --->
    <?php
}
```

If that's not the case, then it's more difficult. I think it would depend on the theme providing a hook at your desired point of insertion.

Another option is to make DOM [manipulations with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385641/how-to-load-some-html-and-append-to-body-with-jquery).

Other quite crazy possibilities can be extracted from this Q&A: [Adding onload to body](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/879/12615)

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

- If you're wanting to put things in the `head` tags, use the `wp_head` action.
- If you're wanting to add markup either override header.php or add actions/filters of your own creation.
- Insert it using javascript

#### Adding a header action

say in header.php I have a large blue square containing a message, and I want to eb able to insert stuff afterwards via a hook, I can do:

```
<div id="bigbluesquare">
    <div id="bigsquaremessage">
        <p>message</p>
    </div>
    <?php do_action('after_big_blue_box_message'); ?>
</div>
```

I can now put in `functions.php` something like this:

```
add_action('after_big_blue_box_message','hello_world');

function hello_world(){
    echo '<p>hello world</p>';
}
```

And hello world will be displayed after the big square message

Of course you will need to add the `do_action` calls in the appropriate places

#### Adding wp_head

This will insert code into the `<head>` tags, and works the same as the above example.

#### Inserting With Javascript

This *might* work, but will assume you know the ID and classes

#### How Do I insert header content That Will Work With Any Theme?

**You can't.**

There is no standard hook that hooks into the header area. It wouldn't make sense on a lot of themes as header layouts vary wildly. Some themes don't have headers.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends upon the theme, what you want to change, and if WordPress and/or the theme provide filters and hooks to accomplish it. A child theme would most likely be your best (and safe) bet.

A simple child theme is very easy to setup and code. Take a look at he CODEX docs [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: So as I understand it, a child theme's `header.php` would need to override parent's with whatever I want it to, right? For that I'll need to copy parent's `header.php` and add to that. But then any updates to the parent theme wouldn't apply, right? So isn't there anything more .. permanent?

Comment: A child theme is the `safe` way to modify/customize a theme. The updates to the parent would still inherit the changes your child theme applies. So it's about as permanent as you can get.

Comment: I just tested and it appears that child theme's `header.php` completely overrides the parent's. As in it doesn't care what's in its parent's `header.php`. Doesn't that mean that any updates to parent's `header.php` wouldn't matter unless they are manually copied to the child?

Comment: Correct your child's `header.php` will take priority, so updates that are specific the parent's `header.php` will not be picked up by your child theme. However you will pick up all of the other updates to the theme.